# Python get access_token from OPS API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, authorization, access-token

I've been trying to connect to the EPO OPS API using the requests package in python - without success. The [dev guide](http://documents.epo.org/projects/babylon/eponet.nsf/0/F3ECDCC915C9BCD8C1258060003AA712/$File/ops_v3.2_documentation_-_version_1.3.6_en.pdf) (page 34) states that Step 1 is to convert Consumer key and Consumer secret to Base64Encode(Consumer key:Consumer secret). Step 2 is to request an access token using Basic Authentication, supplying its Consumer key and Consumer secret with base64Encoding over encrypted HTTPS connection as follows:

[image]

Below is the code I've used but I get an error 400 status.

```
import requests
import base64
url_token = "https://ops.epo.org/3.2/auth/accesstoken"
key = "Basic %s" %base64.b64encode("myconsumerkey:mysecretkey")
headers = ({"Authorization": key, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
resp = requests.post(url_token, headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
```

Anyone knows how to make the access_token request work?

I'd like the script to extract the XML content of this link:

"http://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/published-data/search?q=automation"

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution for this one, I forgot to add the grant_type parameter. Solution below:

```
import requests
import base64
import json

token_url='https://ops.epo.org/3.2/auth/accesstoken'
key = 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(b'myconsumerkeyhere:mysecretkeyhere').decode('ascii')
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
headers = {'Authorization': key, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post(token_url, data=data, headers=headers)

rs= r.content.decode() 
response = json.loads(rs)

token = response['access_token']

print(token)
```